# masquerade an URL with proxy SSL or other methods

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, perl, opensuse

good day dear server experts

I would like to be able to masquerade an URL, that is to keep the URL the
user is entering when going to a page. For example:
The user is entering at his browser:

mydomain.com

This must be forwarded to:

otherdomain.com

But on his browser, the address displayed must stay mydomain.com
I would like to configure this - but how:!!?

Has anyone an idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible if you

- own mydomain.com, so that you can set up a reverse proxy there
- use this reverse proxy to forward to otherdomain.com, e.g. the user will still connect to mydomain.com, but you will redirect all traffic to otherdomain.com

Unfortunatly this will break, if otherdomain.com will contain pages which link to URLs with the hostname otherdomain.com (e.g. absolute URLs containing a hostname). If the user follows them it will connect directly to otherdomain.com, e.g. without your reverse proxy, and this will show up in the browser.

Another way might be to use frames, e.g. frame otherdomain.com inside a page of mydomain.com. This will break if otherdomain.com sets HTTP headers for security, so that it does not get framed or if it contains which explicitly open a new window or tab.